iOS 18 Opus Audio Decoding Issues with Audio Queue Services (Garbled Audio)
I'm encountering garbled audio playback when recording Opus audio from the microphone using Audio Queue services on a physical iPhone running iOS 18. The same code works flawlessly on iOS 16 and 17 devices, including the iPhone simulator. The audio also decodes correctly on iOS 18 devices when running in the simulator.
The following struct is defined to hold information about the audio stream:
    struct RecordState {
        weak var recorder: AudioRecorder?
        var format: AudioStreamBasicDescription
        var queue: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef?>
        var buffers: [AudioQueueBufferRef?]
        var file: AudioFileID?
        var currentPacket: Int64
        var recording: Bool
    }

RecordState(recorder: self,
            format: AudioStreamBasicDescription(),
            queue: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef?>.allocate(capacity: 1),
            buffers: [AudioQueueBufferRef?](repeating: nil, count: 1),
            file: nil,
            currentPacket: 0,
            recording: false)

The audio format for Opus is defined as:
    recordState.format.mSampleRate = 48_000.0
    recordState.format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatOpus
    recordState.format.mFramesPerPacket = 960
    recordState.format.mChannelsPerFrame = 1

Then the buffers are allocated and the audio queue is started.
AudioQueueNewInput(&recordState.format, inputAudioQueueCallback, &recordState, nil, nil, 0, recordState.queue)

AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(recordState.queue.pointee!, 1024, &recordState.buffers[0])

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch {
    return
}
recordState.currentPacket = 0
status = AudioQueueStart(recordState.queue.pointee!, nil)
            return
        }

The InputAudioQueueCallback splits up the packets and forwards the audio samples to an engine which creates an array of data to be sent to the remote client for decoding.
inputAudioQueueCallback = {(
    userData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
    audioQueue: AudioQueueRef,
    bufferQueue: AudioQueueBufferRef,
    startTime: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    packets: UInt32,
    packetDescription: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?) in
    
    let internalRS = unsafeBitCast(userData, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<RecordState>.self)
    internalRS.pointee.currentPacket += Int64(packets)
    if packets > 0 {
        let data = bufferQueue.pointee.mAudioData
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(internalRS.pointee.queue.pointee!, bufferQueue, 0, nil)
        if let packetDescription = packetDescription {
            for packetIndex in 0..<packets {
                let description = packetDescription.advanced(by: Int(packetIndex)).pointee
                let packetOffset = description.mStartOffset
                let packetSize = description.mDataByteSize
                internalRS.pointee.recorder?.feedSamplesToEngine(capacity: packetSize, audioData: data + (Int(packetOffset)))
            }
        }
    }
}

Expected Behavior:
The expected behavior is that the recorded audio should decode correctly and play back without distortion on iOS 18 devices.
Actual Behavior:
The audio playback on iOS 18 devices is garbled.
Troubleshooting Steps:
Simulators: The code works as expected on simulators running iOS 16 and 18.1.
Previous Versions: The code works as expected on physical iPhones running iOS 16 and 17.
Packet Count: In iOS 16 and below, the packets parameter in the AudioQueueInputCallback is usually 1 or 0. In iOS 17 and 18, I often receive multiple packets (e.g., packets = 2).
Packet Descriptions: I'm using AudioStreamPacketDescription to handle variable-length Opus packets, but I'm unsure if there are changes in how these descriptions are handled in iOS 18.
Question:
What could be causing the garbled audio playback on iOS 18 devices when using Opus encoding with Audio Queue services? Could there be changes to the audio encoding, packet handling, or AudioStreamPacketDescription structure in iOS 18 that are not documented?
Additional Details:
Prior Work: The previous developers who wrote this code are no longer available.
Possible Issue: I suspect the garbled audio is related to the way the audio queue delivers multiple packets in the callback. I'm trying to extract subsets of the data correctly using AudioStreamPacketDescription, but I'm unsure if my code is handling the data correctly in iOS 18.
